# How to add robust error variances in glm Poisson model in R?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, stata, robust-standard-error

I am running two parallel analyses for log poisson regression in R and State. In Stata, there is an option of specifying "robust" within the code, but within the R code:

```
model <- glm(outcome~exposure, family=poissson(link=log), data=dataset)
```

I need the robust error variances to be implemented in R because the point estimates are the same (after exponentiation), but my confidence intervals are consistently wider. Does anyone know how to do this in R?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using the `sandwich` package in R. The basic so-called "robust" standard errors are available in function `sandwich()`. To apply these to the usual marginal Wald tests you can use the `coeftest()` function from the `lmtest` package:

```
library("sandwich")
library("lmtest")
coeftest(model, vcov = sandwich)
```

For more details on other types of robust standard errors and further options for conducting/reporting inference results see the project web page at: https://sandwich.R-Forge.R-project.org/